# Validators angular

Tags: angular, angular-custom-validators

I am trying to force Validators.required for the password field in the same modal. If it is an update, it will not catch Validators.required otherwise it will get an error. Help me! Thanks you!

```
userForm() {
  const special = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*$/;
  this.UserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(special)]],
    birthDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
    gender: [0, [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [this.ifEditUser ? Validators.required : '', Validators.maxLength(64)]],
    fullName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
    passwordRe: ['']
  },
  {
    validator: MustMatch('password', 'passwordRe')
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove single inverted comma after `Validators.required` like as following

```
userForm() {
  this.UserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    password: ['', [this.ifEditUser ? Validators.required : Validators.maxLength(64)]]
  });
}
```

For showing error use this below code

```
<small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="UserForm.controls.password.errors && !ifEditUser">
  Maximum 64 characters are allowed.
</small>
```

and also add this following line with submit button. Submit button will automatically disable when your form is not valid.

```
<input [disabled]="!UserForm.valid" type="submit">
```

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code `this.ifEditUser ? Validators.required : ''` is not good practice.

It is better to use `setValidators` method inside `ngOnInit` or inside your method to add validator conditionally.

Code will looks like

```
const passwordControl = this.UserForm.getControl('passowrd');
if (this.ifEditUser) {
  passwordControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```

If ifEditUser is changed on demand then you also need to use `passwordControl.updateValueAndValidity();`

Comment: I have tried but not yet. Can you describe it more specifically? Thanks you!

Comment: I suggest to check the following: 1) check that validator is really connected to the control - add 'debugger' somewhere you expect it to be working, get control and its validators. 2) If a validator is there then keep password field empty and check its 'valid' property in debugger again.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom validator, for example, the following `requiredIfValidator` generic validation function, which takes a predicate and based on the predicate value makes the form control required or not

```
requiredIfValidator(predicate) {
    return (formControl => {
      if (!formControl.parent) {
        return null;
      }
      if (predicate()) {
        return Validators.required(formControl);
      }
      return null;
    })
  }
```

And the form:

```
 userForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [0],
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(128)]],
    password: ['', [this.requiredIfValidator(() => this.ifEditUser)]],
    passwordRe: ['']
  });
```